# I can't deploy despite having permissions on gcloud

Tags: deployment, permissions, gcloud

When I try to deploy my project the following error appears: 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) 403 Could not list bucket [page-example.com]: example@example.com does not have storage.objects.list access to page-example.com.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to update the gcloud components 
with this command:

```
gcloud components update
```

Then log in again with your account.

```
gcloud auth login
```

With that you can deploy your web application.